# Need to introduce 3 part logic when importing csv data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

In mysql is there a way to evaluate during LOAD DATA, whether or not a record exists in the database, but not in the imported data based on a multi column index?

Example:

Updating a record in the database if the Name + UID exists in database, and the Name with other UIDs exists in the import, but the import does not include some Name + UID that is in the database.

If not, perhaps it is just easier to run a query periodically that updates records from Name + UID combos where the matching Name has records with a newer create date, or update date for other UIDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this in a relatively straight forward manner. That being said, I am still interested to know if anyone has a simpler / more efficient way of doing this in MySQL (MariaDB 5.7)

I have a multi-column Index on Host+CVE to catch duplicates. I also have a createDate and updateDate column. The createDate update automatically on import, and the updateDate updates automatically on import, or on record Update except if the record updateDate happens during the import process below (I want to keep track of the last time we actually touched the record with our GUI).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/Example.csv' INTO TABLE ExampleImport
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

INSERT INTO ExampleTable (PluginID,CVE,CVSS,Risk,Host,Protocol,Port,Name,Synopsis,Description,Solution,SeeAlso,PluginOutPut)
SELECT PluginID, CVE, CVSS, Risk, Host, Protocol, Port, Name, Synopsis, Description, Solution, SeeAlso, PluginOutput
FROM ExampleImport 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ImportDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, UpdateDate = UpdateDate;

UPDATE ExampleTable x4 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Host, MAX(UpdateDate) MaxDate 
        FROM ExampleTable
        GROUP BY Host
        ) x2 ON x4.Host = x2.Host
SET FixDate = CURDATE(), x4.UpdateDate = x4.UpdateDate
WHERE x4.UpdateDate < x2.MaxDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would start by putting a unique index on `UniqueID` and `Name` this will make sure that the database knows that the combination of those two would be a `Duplicate Key` then your PDO would look something like

```
INSERT INTO `myTbl` (`UniqueID`,`Name`,`FixedDate`)
VALUES :UniqueID, :Name, :FixedDate
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `FixedDate` = VALUES(FixedDate)
```

Comment: Hmm, to me this looks like it would update the fixed date if both files contain the Name+UID, but I only want to update the fixed date if the import doesn't have a Name+UID that exists in the database. Think remediation of scan results